# Python equivalent for TurboPascal's plot (x , y, colour)?

Tags: python, graphics

In TurboPascal I can set a pixel on the display by using:

```
Plot (x, y, colour)
```

What is the equivalent in Python?  How do I set or unset individual pixels in Python?

Comment: This is _way_ too broad.  Are you using a gui framework?

Comment: If you're interested in producing a plot instead of modifying the actual screen, you might look into the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) module. Here's a simple [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several helpful libraries in python that will help you. I would say [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) or [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) are both decent options for drawing. Pyglet is wrapper to Opengl in python, but it will let you control pixels. If you're just trying to do a crude pixel set without any other drawing functionality the python Imaging library allows you to do it like this:

```
pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map

for i in range(img.size[0]):    # for every pixel:
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        pixels[i,j] = (i, j, 100) # set the colour accordingly
```